# Not able to sum values while using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have created a script for calculating the sum of all the values in 32th column which has comma as delimiter. My script is printing the values but unable to sum the values. What I am doing wrong? Below is my script:

```
import numpy as np
b=np.loadtxt(r'FileP3806520150316142845.txt',dtype=str,delimiter=',',skiprows=0,usecols=(31,))
print b
a = b[1].sum(0)
print a
```

I can print variable b, but not a.

```
python myreport.sh 
['1' '438' '18' '987' '1472' '95' '52' '2' '22' '137' '7' '22']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "myreport.sh", line 4, in <module>
a = b[1].sum(0)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

Also I am just running this script on one file. Can this be applied to all files in a folder or all files in a tar file?

Comment: The elements of b are strings, not a numeric type.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting `dtype=int`. Numpy doesn't know what to do with a bunch of strings.

You can also convert `b` after the fact:

```
b_ints = np.int_(b)
```

Comment: Yes thanks. setting dtype to int worked. Is there a way that I can apply this script to all files in a folder, or all files in a zip?

Comment: Many different ways! ☺ Try searching for that here on SO.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-directory-with-extension-txt-with-python for example